# Получение данных из json с помощью ajax и их отрисовка в dom

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

Нужно словить json файл с помощью ajax и отрисовать его данные в dom через цикл for. Вот код:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
    if(xhr.readyState !=4) return;
    if(xhr.status !=200) {
        console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
    } else {
        console.log(xhr.response);
    }
});
xhr.open("GET", "https://js.dump.academy/code-and-magick/data");
xhr.send();
var similarWizardTemplate = document.querySelector('#similar-wizard-template').content.querySelector(".setup-similar-item");
var similarWizardList = document.querySelector('.setup-similar-list');
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var wizardsElements = similarWizardTemplate.cloneNode(true);
    wizardsElements.querySelector('.setup-similar-label').textContent = 'данные из JSON'[i].name;
    wizardsElements.querySelector('.wizard-coat').style.fill = 'данные из JSON'[i].colorCoat;
    wizardsElements.querySelector('.wizard-eyes').style.fill = 'данные из JSON'[i].colorEyes;
    similarWizardList.appendChild(wizardsElements);
};
```

Comment: Круто, а что не получается или в чем у вас проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, Вы не в том месте делаете обработку полученного результата. Вот Ваш пример, только немного переписан, вместо `addEventListener` используется `onreadystatechange`. Собственно, внутрь этой функции и поместите обработку вашего результата в переменной `jsonResponse` объявленную мной внутри метода:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.open("GET", "https://js.dump.academy/code-and-magick/data", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;

  if (xhr.status != 200) {
    console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
  } else {
    var jsonResponse = xhr.response; // вот тут должен быть ваш JSON в ответе
    // далее работа с переменной jsonResponse в которой лежит ответ (данные из JSON)
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

В `open` указан третий аргумент `true` (или если третьего аргумента нет) и запрос выполняется асинхронно. Это означает, что после вызова `xhr.send()` код не «зависает», а продолжает выполняться, а результат ответа на запрос приходит через событие `onreadystatechange`. Событие `readystatechange` происходит несколько раз в процессе отсылки и получения ответа, состояние `readyState` - 4 (запрос завершён).

**Небольшой примечание**: В IE8 и IE9 поддержка XMLHttpRequest ограничена. IE9 по умолчанию кеширует все ответы. В IE11 запись `xhr.responseType = 'json'` не сработает в силу того, что это не поддерживается в нем. Если не указать тип запроса как JSON, то искать нужно в `responseText`, а не в `response` свой результат. Это касается конфигурирования с использованием типа `application/json` или при отсутсвиии указания `responseType`.

В данном случае сервер должен возвращать JSON в виде текста, который браузер превращает в объект вызовом `JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)` (в неашем случае это `JSON.parse(xhr.response)`) и мы работаем с полученным ответом как с объектом.

Также, советую почитать про параметры `xhr.open(method, URL, async, user, password)` - обратите внимание на третий параметр `async` - который указывает, как будет выполнен запрос (если установлено в false, то запрос производится синхронно, если true – асинхронно).

Полезные ссылки для изучения:

- [Основы XMLHttpRequest](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest)
- [Parsing JSON from XmlHttpRequest.responseJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8416963/5275890)

Comment: Да я это понял. Я не понимаю как мне в цикле for обращаться к xhr.response

Comment: @RavenTheX внутри функции я оставил переменную `jsonResponse` - в ней ответ лежит (немного обновил свой ответ, вместо `onload` использовал `readystatechange`). Это ваш объект, значит сюда (сразу после переменной) можете положить ваш цикл - это и будет обработка результата.

Comment: Спасибо Вам, получилось